# Posicion antes y despues en un arreglo

Tags: c++, dev-c++, c++11

Lo que quiero es hacer esto:

Busca la primera ocurrencia del entero 7 en la subsecuencia posterior a "p1" pero anterior a "p2" . Si existe, reemplázala por el entero . En caso contrario, ordena la subsecuencia mencionada.

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
introducir el código aquí
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){

int a;

cin>>a;

int arr[a];

for(int i=0; i<a; i++){
    cin>>arr[i];
}

int* r = find(&arr[0],&arr[a],5);
int* t = find(r+1,&arr[a],5);
int* p = find(&arr[0],&arr[a],7);

if(*r == 5 && *t == 5){
    reverse(&arr[0],r);
    reverse(t+1,&arr[a]);
}

if(*p == 7){
    *p = 0;
}else{
    sort(r+1,t-1);
}

for(int i=0; i<a; i++){
    cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
}   

}
```

Ya tengo la parte donde reemplaza por un 0 y la de ordena pero no se como hacer la parte de posterior y anterior. Como lo puedo escribir en codigo.

Esto es un ejemplo de como debe de quedar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Ya tienes todo hecho con aritmética de punteros, así que ya casi lo tienes.

Entiendo que deberías pedir los valores `p1` y `p2` y reemplazar éstos por los que usas ahora mismo para inicializar `r` y `t`

```
int p1, p2;
std::cin >> p1 >> p2;

int* r = find(arr, arr+a, p1);
int* t = find(r+1, arr+a, p2);
```

Por otro lado, deberías buscar el número 7 únicamente en el rango dado por `r` y `t`:

```
int* p = find(r, t, 7);
```